# Get Eval value from Gridview from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that loads from a database that has several TemplateFields. How do I retrieve the Eval value from code behind? In other words I need the template field name for that column.

I want to get "Registrations" and store it in a variable.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="REG" SortExpression="Registrations">
     <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="cbRegEdit" runat="server" Checked='<%# (int)Eval("Registrations") == 1 %>' />
     </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbReg" runat="server" Enabled="false" Checked='<%# (int)Eval("Registrations") == 1 %>'>
                 </asp:CheckBox>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to hook to `OnRowDataBound` and do something like:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    var registrations = ((YourType)e.Row.DataItem).Registrations;
    //do something 
  }
}
```

Your GridView would then have to be:

```
<asp:GridView OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ...
```

Comment: var registrations = ((YourType)e.Row.DataItem).Registrations; Does not have the .Registrations property

Comment: @Apollo how are you binding the data to your gridview? Are these business objects or are you binding a DataSet or a DataTable. `YourType` in my example was meant to be whatever object collection you are binding.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to assign a [datakey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your gridview.

An example would be like this:

```
<asp:Gridview ID="gvExample" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Registrations">
```

Then in the code behind all you need is the row index and you can do the following:

```
gvExample.Datakeys(rowindex).value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            CheckBox CBreg = (Page.FindControl("cbReg") as CheckBox);
            bool Reg = CBreg.Checked;   //Reg value stored
```

You may need to change Page.FindControl to your TemplateField control ID if you cannot find the control this way.